# Run script before other units stop on shutdown

Tags: linux, debian, shutdown, systemd, debian-stretch

I need to run a script before a set of other services on my machine stop when shutting the machine down. (In my case, terminating an EC2 instance.)

I have tried variations on the answer in this question but nothing works: [How do I run a script before everything else on shutdown with systemd?](https://superuser.com/questions/1016827/how-do-i-run-a-script-before-everything-else-on-shutdown-with-systemd) (I also looked at unix.se, but it's also no good: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39226/how-to-run-a-script-with-systemd-right-before-shutdown... and I looked in mailing lists too.)

My biggest problem is that the OP of that question wanted to run the script before some mounts were unmounted but I don't have any requirements on mounts, but rather on services.

My service is something like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Run script before other things stop on shutdown
Wants=multi-user.target network.target foo.service bar.service
After=multi-user.target network.target foo.service bar.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=-/my/script
ExecStopPost=/bin/sleep 5s
RemainAfterExit=yes
Type=oneshot

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I enable and start this unit after boot, but it doesn't seem to run the script when I shut the instance down. I'm at a loss, how can I do this?

I am using systemd 232 on Debian Stretch.

Comment: "…but I don't have anything like that." – of course you do, you even mentioned it in your 1st paragraph: you have "before a set of other services on my machine stop".

Comment: @grawity I was specifically referring to mounts

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the ExecStop isn't running because the ExecStart process has already terminated?

If that's the case, set `ExecStart=/bin/sleep infinity`.

Comment: OP already has `RemainAfterExit=` for that purpose.